# Expedite process in India

Tags: india, expedite

I am from India have a filed an ordinary patent application in India. I have my co-applicant as lady but now she is not alive. Can I apply for expedite procedure (where applications with women applicants are done in faster way) with my mam's documents when she is not alive?